# How can I avoid the gap between a scrollbar and scrolled content when using background-clip: padding-box?

Tags: html, css

I've styled my scrollbar with some CSS and want to use background-clip. My real-world setup is much more complex (eg: I'm using a border image). This example shows the problem: There is a 1-pixel wide gap between the scrollbar and the content. Also, there is a 1-pixel gap at the bottom. Why does this happen?

I know I can fix this, by using an extra container or something like this, but I want to analyze the problem. Is there any extra property I've missed to fix this? I already tried `-webkit-scrollbar-corner`.

Note: I've tested this in chromium-based browsers. I don't know the behavior in IE, Safari, etc.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.scroll {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #aaa;
  border: 5px solid #666;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to style the `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` instead.  That will get rid of that border issue.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.scroll {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: green;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 5px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you test this in Opera/Chrome? Does not work for me. The gap is still there.

Comment: Chrome and Safari.  No gap for me...but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?  I've attached a screen shot to my code above for verification.

Comment: Do you have the issue in my example? I think it's a rounding thing. My screen rendering is set to 125% under windows. May be this is the issue?

Comment: Actually, no issue with your example on my mac in Chrome or Safari.  Yeah, that zoom level sounds like the culprit.

Comment: The question is, how can I avoid this rounding issues? Does it happen on a Mac, when zooming in to the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `border-box` value for the [`background-clip`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp) property, which is the default behaviour.

```css
    body {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .scroll {
      max-width: 300px;
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: green;
      background-clip: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: green;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #aaa;
      border: 5px solid #666;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background: green;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This will not work. My border is half-transparent (using the border-image property in conjunction with an svg image). The background should not overlap the border.